# Convert recursive tree walking function to iterative

Tags: python, recursion, tree, iteration

How can the following recursive function `walk()` be converted to an iterative function?

Walking the nodes in the same order iteratively is easy using a stack, but I'm unable to figure out how to write an iterative function that will print both the opening and closing tags of each node like the recursive version does.

**Code:**

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, children=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

def walk(node):
    print('<', node.name, '>', sep='')
    for n in node.children:
        walk(n)
    print('</', node.name, '>', sep='')

root = \
Node('html', [
    Node('head'),
    Node('body', [
        Node('div'),
        Node('p', [
            Node('a'),
        ])
    ]),
])

walk(root)
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
<p>
<a>
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code that traverses the tree iteratively:**

The function visits the nodes in the correct order, but obviously does not print the closing tags.

```
def walk(node):
    stack = []
    stack.append(node)
    while len(stack) > 0:
        node = stack.pop()
        for child in reversed(node.children):
            stack.append(child)
        print(node.name)
```

Comment: Show your iterative function that only partially solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for this to work you also need to record on the stack where the node ends. A possible solution would be:

```
def walk(root):
    stack = []
    stack.append(root)
    indent = 0
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(node, Node):
            print('    ' * indent, "<", node.name, ">", sep="")
            indent += 1
            stack.append(node.name)
            stack.extend(reversed(node.children))
        else:
            indent -= 1
            print('    ' * indent, "</", node, ">", sep="")
```

I've added indenting so the output is nicer:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
        <p>
            <a>
            </a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of [post-order tree treversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)  as you have to visit the parent node after visiting children.

I modified a few lines of your existing code:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, name, children=[]):
    self.name = name
    self.children = children

# def walk(node):
#     print('<', node.name, '>', sep='')
#     for n in node.children:
#         walk(n)
#     print('</', node.name, '>', sep='')

def walk(node):
    stack = []
    stack.append((node, 'start'))
    while len(stack) > 0:
        node, status = stack.pop()
        if status == 'start':
            stack.append((node, 'end'))
            for child in reversed(node.children):
                stack.append((child, 'start'))
            print('<', node.name, '>', sep='')
        else: # status == 'end'
            print('</', node.name, '>', sep='')

root = \
Node('html', [
    Node('head'),
    Node('body', [
        Node('div'),
        Node('p', [
            Node('a'),
        ])
    ]),
])

walk(root)
```